# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; laravel9

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, laravel-9

Buenas tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE productos SET productos.id_producto = @count:= @count + 1;

ALTER TABLE productos  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Dicha consulta funciona correctamente al ejecutarla directamente desde el RUN SQL de phpmyadmin
Pero al ejecutarla desde un controlador  de laravel 9 me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo en laravel

```
 DB::statement('
        SET @count = 0;
UPDATE productos SET productos.id_producto = @count:= @count + 1;

ALTER TABLE productos  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
        ');
```

Comment: El bloque de sentencias, ¿no debería dentro de un bloque `begin...end`? Porque así me parece que no es atómica la ejecución.

Comment: como seria eso disculpa?,podrias explicar mejor?